# Return autosuggestion search with swift xcode

Tags: swift, xml, xcode, search, filter

I have a search bar that filters through an xml array of recipe titles. The problem is that I have to search the entire title, otherwise I don't see suggested results. For example, if I have "Whole Grain Waffles" and "Whole Wheat Bread" typing "Whole" returns nothing. Typing "Whole Grain Waffles" returns successfully. This is the `searchBar` function

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredData = tableViewDataSource.filter({$0.title == searchBar.text})
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

I'm pretty sure the solution has to do with case sensitivity, and returning certain characters when setting the `filteredData`. Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use `contains` to filter any item in array that contains the text or you can also use `hasPrefix`, if you want to search for the strings that start with the search text.

Something like this,

```
filteredData  = tableViewDataSource.filter { $0.title.contains(searchBar.text) ?? "" }
```

Or,

```
filteredData = tableViewDataSource.filter { $0.title.hasPrefix(searchBar.text) ?? "" }
```

Comment: I've seen similar answers online, but have object type compatibility errors like "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')". I found that range works

Comment: What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Currently using swift 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Using `range` worked in my situation

```
filteredData = tableViewDataSource.filter({$0.title.range(of: searchBar.text!) != nil})
```